# Best control for display boolean readonly data

Tags: forms, checkboxes

Now we are using readonly checkboxes for displaying some information about other users:

**Mike Angel**

[image]

And I feel that using input elements for displaying readonly data is wrong, but I cannot think of a better solution and don't know the reasons to convince my coworkers to change this elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason to change this is pretty obvious: users are likely to think that they can edit the information when it looks like that.  They will be confused, and they might even think your app is "broken" when they try to select or unselect a checkbox and it doesn't work.

If you replaced the checkbox with a green check mark that had no box around it, it would rectify this while being a minimally disruptive change to your interface.

As long as there was always at least one item in the list selected, having the green check mark only might be enough.  But if there could be zero items selected, this wouldn't be clear enough--without seeing any green check marks, it wouldn't be clear that the items aren't selected. You would also need another cue that the other items aren't selected, such as putting a red X next to them.